# How to find a Orc from a specific tribe in Shadow of War?

Tags: middle-earth-shadow-of-war

I want to get the Marauder Legendary set in the Shadow of War. I found the list on what to do to get each item

```
Gear                How To Unlock
Marauder Sword      Kill a Legendary Marauder Slayer or Marauder Berserker
Marauder Dagger     Kill a Legendary Marauder Assassin or Marauder Tracker
Marauder Bow        Kill a Legendary Marauder Marksman
Marauder Armor      Kill a Legendary Marauder Tank or Marauder Destroyer
Marauder Cloak      Kill a Legendary Marauder Beastmaster or Marauder Trickster
Marauder Ringcraft  Kill a Legendary Marauder Commander
```

How do I find the orc of the specific tribe? After some research I saw that in the Orc's subtitle name the tribe is written however I have been running around and I could not find a Marauder yet. In addition consider there is a desired Maurauder orc how can I make him Legendary. Some guides mention that I just need to die to him and the orc becomes legendary however if I am correct this is only Based on probability.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you can interrogate orcs to know the identity of captains or warchiefs, once you have informations on them, you can browse to seek what you look for. Unfortunately, every tribes can be found in every zones, it is random as the class they will have. Don't hesitate to kill the ones that doesn't fit your needs and wait time at the tower so new orcs will replace them.

To make your orc legendary, you can let him kill you a bunch of time but you can also make him fight your followers by ambushing him and letting him win, death threating him etc. Another risky method is to kill them and hope they will "cheat death"

Comment: Or recruit the orc, make him legendary and beat him up untill he betrays you. Then simply kill him. Note that making the orc your bodyguard makes it easier to stab him in the back.